# Counting cells with specific value through non contiguous columns

Tags: excel, count

I need a formula to count the number of cells that contain "0" on non contiguous ranges.

[image: example]

I need to count the number of cells on "Q" columns (A,C,E,G,I,K,M) that contains "0" on row 2 (putting the result on "O2"). As you can see, there may be some "0" on "Comments" columns, so creating one big range is not an option (look at "H2"). The output should be "2", since "C2" and "K2" are the only ones with "0"

The real sheet is actually much longer, so i would appreciate a short approaching, maybe an array formula.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` to count with multiple criteria and also check the columns of each of the values before summing the count:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((NOT(ISBLANK(A2:N2)))*(A2:N2=0)*(MOD(COLUMN(A2:N2),2)))
```

By using the [MOD](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/MOD-function-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3) function you can check whether the column number is divisible by 2, if not it will return the remainder of 1. Columns that are divisible by 2 (your comments) will return 0 and therefore will not be counted. To reverse this (if the values you wanted to count ARE on even columns) simply add one to the columns before using the `MOD` function.

Like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((NOT(ISBLANK(A2:N2)))*(A2:N2=0)*(MOD(COLUMN(A2:N2)+1,2)))
```

I've also added a check to ensure that blank cells are not counted however you can remove `(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:N2)))*` if you did want to count blanks.

**If the gap between the questions is more than 1 column this formula will not work**

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm! i wasn't aware of mod function and how it works.